# Openlayers how to show polygon only on mouseover, and hide on mouseout?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Any suggestions on how i can show a polygon only on mouseover? I am thinking it must be possible to set the initial fillOpacity and strokeOpacity to 0 on the style object.

And then attach a mouseover and mouseout listener to the polygon itself, and modify the fillOpacity and strokeOpacity style upon invocation of the listeners?

However, im a bit stuck on actually how to get started with this.

Any guidance and help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried adding an [`OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature`](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/SelectFeature-js.html) and set `hover` to `true`? That's how I did it. You are right about changing the polygons opacity.

Comment: Yes i have tried that, but then that interferes with another event i have, which namely is onclick. so either i need another solution to handle hover. Or i need somehow to differentiate the hover and the click event. any suggestions?

Comment: Does this mean you want to be able to both, hover and select (by clicking) the polygons?

Comment: Yes, however the click event creates a popup with some text, but should only do so if the the polygon is visible e.g. hovered.

Comment: i think i might have found a solution here: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/1596, ill take a look at it an try it out.

Comment: Yes, have a look at that... if it does not work for you, I created my own `SelectFeature` control which does exactly that (well it's stays selected until you click on an other polygon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it using:

```
           new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(this.layer,{
                clickout: true, toggle: false,
                multiple: true, hover: true,
                callbacks: {
                    'over':function(feature){

                    },
                    'out':function(feature){

                    },
                    'click':function(feature){

                    }
                }
            })
```